# Download result of Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a release pipeline that combines two build pipelines artifacts to create the full release.  I need to be able to download the result of this task after is done.

I run the Archive Task to zip the results but I don't know how to save it somewhere where I can download it using the Azure Pipeline agent.

Is there a task that can trigger that as a download or can I save it as an Artifact?

Thank you

Comment: Do you use YAML for pipelines and release? Or not?

Comment: No, I'm using the classic pipeline.

Comment: So you need to use publish pipeline artifact task.

Comment: That does not work on Release Pipeline unless is to a file share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that if I do this with my On-Prem agent I can get the file form the agent's file structure.

Would be nice though if I could get the file straight from Azure instead.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what you have to do is publish and then consume artifact in your Release pipeline. Here you have [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

```
steps:
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
  artifact: WebApp
```

Id you use Yaml then you should use this:

```
steps:
- download: current
  artifact: WebApp
```

If you use Classic releases you needs to confgure it on designer.

Please use this task in your pipeline:

[image]

and then configure your release here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The part of having the Artifacts on the Build Pipeline I have already working.  Also the part where I combine both Build Pipeline Artifacts on the release.  What I'm try to obtain is, instead of deploying to an App Services or On-Prem server I want that final result as a zip that I can download.  Publish does not work on Release Pipelines unless I give it a share which I don't have.

Comment: To be sure I understood you. You want to download two artifacts, zip them and publish as another artitact?

Comment: Yes, something like that, During the release I copy our FE Artifact into the API artifact.  Modify some files on those using powershell.  Then I zip the updated API artifact.  I want to get that zip.  Normally after these transformations I deploy to either an App Services or On-Prem server, which works fine but I want a zip with different values on some of the transformations.

Comment: You can't publish this on release pipeline. You can hower do another build pipeline. The you will use [`Download Build Artifacts task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops), do some transformation what you need, then publis as another artifact and finally use this artifact for your release pipeline.

Comment: I will give this a shot as I like it better than digging on my agent's directory structure.

Comment: Try this task but everytime I select the Build where the artifacts are and go to the next task, The Build pipeline option resets to 101 and turns into an error.